# Finding linearly dependent set of continous real function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $C[0,1]$ be set of real valued continous functions on $[0,1]$. Which one of following subsets of $C[0,1]$ is linearly dependent?

1. $\{1, \cos t , \sin t\}$
2. $\{ \tan^2t, \cos^2t, \sin^2t\}$
3. $\{1, \cos^2t, \sin^2t\}$
4. $\{\tan t, \cos t, \sin t\}$

My attempt:

Wronskian of option 3 is zero. So it will be linearly dependent. Is this way correct? Or is there some other way?

Answer (score 0):

That is the normal way,  you can also pretty clearly see that option 3 has a linear combination that adds up to be 0:  $\cos ^2t +\sin ^2 t-1=0$